# evaluating $\iiint\limits_E x \; dV$; $E$ between $x=ay^2+az^2$ and $x=a$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, 3d, multiple-integral

$\iiint\limits_{x=ay^2+az^2}^{x=a} \!\!\!\!\! x \; dV$ (is writing integral limits like this fine?)
in my head this volume looks like an x-axis paraboloid up to the unit circle
I try to use cylindrical coordinates along the x axis with $x,\; \theta, \text{ and } r$
my limits then look like: $\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_0^a\int\limits_0^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}}x\;dr\;dx\;d\theta$
then evaluating one integral at a time I get
$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_0^a\int\limits_0^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}}x\;dr\;dx\;d\theta=
 \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_0^a    \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}x^{\frac{3}{2}}  \;dx\;d\theta=
 \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}                   \frac{2}{5\sqrt{a}}a^{\frac{5}{2}}     \;d\theta=
 \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}                   \frac{2}{5}a^2                         \;d\theta=
                                          \frac{4\pi a^2}{5}                               $

plugging it into a online calculator using rectangular coordinates gives $\frac{\pi a^2}{3}$, so I deff did something wrong somewhere in there

Comment: Check the bounds for $x$. From your triple integral one may conclude $0 \le x \le a$.

Comment: Check the bounds for $r$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plot of such region using Mathematica when $a = 1$:

[image]

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you take slices of the paraboloid at $x$ where $0 \le x \le a $, then
the cross section you will obtain is

$ x = a (y^2 + z^2) $

which is a circle whose squared radius is $\dfrac{x}{a} $, and therefore its area is $ \dfrac{\pi x}{a} $, and hence $dV = \dfrac{\pi x dx}{a}$

The integral then is

$ I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{a} \dfrac{\pi x^2 dx}{a} = \dfrac{ \pi a^2}{3} $

Comment: ok, I think I got the first half, where we simplify it to an area changing over x so that we only need one integral, but I don't think I get the last steps you took.